# wp: footer text in different languages

Tags: php, wordpress

i have wp website that translated to two languages .. i want to change footer copy right using php but below code is not working .. any help?

```html
add_filter('botiga-credits','socket_per_language');
function socket_per_language(){ 
$currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');

if($currentlang=="en-US") {
$output = "your custom text in English";
}
elseif($currentlang=="de-DE") {
$output = "your custom text in German";
}
else{
$output = "your custom text in Dutch";
}
return $output;
}
```

Comment: tried to use wp translation? __() function

Comment: Read the [doc of `_()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/), read [tutorial](https://wpmudev.com/blog/translating-wordpress-plugins/).